# C Compiler: not found in Clion

Tags: c, clion

I've installed Clion and MinGW, however in setting for Clion I get a message saying that C Compiler is not found. As shown here:
[image]

Although I believe I've installed all variations of the `gcc` package as shown:
[image]

It also appears I'm missing `gcc.exe`:

[image]

Anyone know what I'm missing and how to correct this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It appears that it wasn't actually downloading and extracting the exe properly.

To fix it I clicked on the general tab for the package I wanted in the package manager, then had to type the Package URL into my browser (can't copy it for some reason). That downloaded the folders, so I just extracted them and put them into their respective directories and Clion now detects the compiler!

The link for my version was `https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/Base/gcc/Version4/gcc-4.9.3-1/gcc-core-4.9.3-1-mingw32-bin.tar.xz/download?use_mirror=iweb`